# Regex to get password from a long string of mess

Tags: regex, powershell

I am using power-shell and am getting the below output from my program.

I am having problems getting the password from the mess of other things. Ideally i need to get **Hiva!!66** by itself. I am using reg-ex to accomplish this and its just not working. the password will always be 8 characters have an upper and a lowercase and a special character. I have created the split and everything else i need but the reg-ex part is messing with me.

I am away that there are a lot of questions around reg-ex and passwords but those don't seem to have a lot of mess before and after it.Any help would be appreciated.
My best attempt so far is:

```
"(?=.*\d)(?=.*[A-Z])(?=.*[!@#\$%\^&\*\~()_\+\-={}\[\]\\:;`"'<>,./]).{8}$"

C:\Users\<username>\AppData\Roaming\Crystal Point\OutsideView\Macro\CONNECTEXP.VCB:5:For intTmp = 1 To 4
C:\Users\<username>\AppData\Roaming\Crystal Point\OutsideView\Macro\CONNECTEXP.VCB:8:cboCOMPort.SelectString 1, "1"
C:\Users\<username>\AppData\Roaming\Crystal Point\OutsideView\Macro\CONNECTEXP.VCB:11:str2CRLF = Chr(13) & Chr(10) & Chr(13) & Chr(10)
C:\Users\<username>\AppData\Roaming\Crystal Point\OutsideView\Macro\CONNECTEXP.VCB:14:    & "include emulation type (currently Tandem), the I/O method (currently Async) and host connection information 
for the session (currently COM9, 8N1)" _
C:\Users\<username>\AppData\Roaming\Crystal Point\OutsideView\Macro\CONNECTEXP.VCB:15:    & " to the correct values for your target host (e.g., TCP/IP and host IP name or address) and save the 
IOSet "CHARSIZE", "8"
PASS="Hiva!!66" If DDEAppReturnCode() <> 0 Then
If DDEAppReturnCode() <> 0 Then
C:\Users\<username>\AppData\Roaming\Crystal Point\OutsideView\Macro\DDEtoXL.vcb:28:    MsgBox "Could not load " & txtWorkSheet.text, 48
C:\Users\<username>\AppData\Roaming\Crystal Point\OutsideView\Macro\DDEtoXL.vcb:37:DDESheetChan = -1
C:\Users\<username>\AppData\Roaming\Crystal Point\OutsideView\Macro\DDEtoXL.vcb:38:DDESystemChan = -2
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you can't count on the quotes or the `PASS=` being there, you'll have to rely on the password's composition to do everything.  The following regex matches a string of eight consecutive characters of the allowed types, with the lookahead and lookbehind to make sure there aren't more than eight.

```
$regex = [regex] @'
(?x)
(?<![!@#$%^&*~()_+\-={}\[\]\\:;`<>,./A-Za-z0-9])
(?:
  [!@#$%^&*~()_+\-={}\[\]\\:;`<>,./]()
  |
  [A-Z]()
  |
  [a-z]()
  |
  [0-9]()
){8}
\1\2\3\4
(?![!@#$%^&*~()_+\-={}\[\]\\:;`<>,./A-Za-z0-9])
'@
```

It also verifies that there's at least one of each character type: uppercase letter, lowercase letter, digit and special.  The lookahead approach used in your regex won't work because it can look *too far* ahead, beyond the end of the word you're trying to match.  Instead, I put an empty group in each branch to act like check boxes.  If a backreference to one of those groups fails, it means that branch didn't participate in the match, meaning in turn that the associated character type was not present.

Answer (score 0):

Did you try the following regex:

```
^PASS="(.{8})"
```

?

Comment: yep i did but sometimes it wont have the word pass in the front. any 8 digit string that has the requirements is what i am after. Upper, lower,special digit and 8 digits. and sometimes it wont have the "" around the password aswell....

Comment: This file is mess. >< Is the password always on the same line? at the beginning of the line? after some specifc / unique word?

Answer (score 0):

Just use this

```
(?<=PASS=").+(?=")
```

Answer (score 0):

You can extract the password from that output with something like this:

```
... | ? { $_ -cmatch 'PASS="(.{8})"' | % { $matches[1] }
```

or like this (in PowerShell v3):

```
... | Select-String -Case 'PASS="(.{8})"' | % { $_.Matches.Groups[1].Value }
```

In PowerShell v2 you'll have to do something like this if you want to use `Select-String`:

```
... | Select-String -Case 'PASS="(.{8})"' | select -Expand Matches |
   select -Expand Groups | select -Last 1 | % { $_.Value }
```